# Sort a flat array with the shortest strings alternating the outermost elements and the longest string in the middle

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, string-length, custom-sort

As an academic/contrived task, I'd like to sort an indexed, 1-dimensional array so that the longest string is in the middle and its neighbouring elements should be the 2nd and 3rd longest and so on.

How can I alternate the position of the shortest strings working from the front and back of the array, and finish with the longest string(s) in the middle?

Sample input:

```
$array = ["Hello", "World", "this", "is", "a", "test"];
```

Desired result:

```
["a", "test", "Hello", "World", "this", "is"]
```

Explanation:

- `a` is shortest and must be positioned first
- `is` is 2nd shortest, so it takes last position
- `test` and `this` are tied for 3rd shortest, alphabetize to break the tie which determines that `test` comes after `a` and `this` comes before `is`
- `Hello` and `World` are tied for the longest strings, so alphabetize to break the tie and position `Hello` after `test` and `World` before `this`

A secondary example with an odd number of elements:

```
$array = ['hundreds', 'human', 'AI', 'replace', 'may', 'developers', 'soon'];
```

Desired result:

```
['AI', 'soon', 'replace', 'developers', 'hundreds', 'human', 'may']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (there's most likely a better solution):

```
function sort_length($str1, $str2)
{
    if(strlen($str1) == strlen($str2))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return strlen($str1) > strlen($str2) ? -1 : 1;
}
$words = array("Hello", "World", "this", "is", "a", "test");
usort($words, 'sort_length');

$new_list = array();
$boolean = true;
foreach($words as $word)
{
    if($boolean)
    {
        array_push($new_list, $word);
    }
    else
    {
        array_unshift($new_list, $word);
    }
    $boolean = !$boolean;
}

//print_r($new_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

1. Sort the original array by length of the strings (with [uasort()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php))
2. Split the array in half by putting every element in one of two arrays (in a foreach loop)
3. Reverse the second array (with [array_reverse()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php))
4. Merge the two array together (with [array_merge()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php))

Comment: No need to re-sort the second half as it’s already sorted. You just have to reverse the order.

Comment: That's why I used the array_reverse function :) Ok I'll change my sentence.

Comment: You will always have a right-heavy array but I believe this still passes the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a solution that preserves the array keys:

```
// function to compare two strings by their length
function cmp_strlen($a, $b) {
    return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
}

// sort array by length while preserving the keys
uasort($arr, 'cmp_strlen');

$ordered = array();
$keys = array_keys($arr);

// fill $ordered with odd keys in order
for ($i=0, $n=count($keys); $i<$n; $i+=2) {
    $ordered[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
}
// fill $ordered with even keys in reverse order
for ($i=((count($keys)>>1)<<1)-1; $i>0; $i-=2) {
    $ordered[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A first attempt could be to first sort them as normal. Then iterate through this array, copying to a new one, with the copy destination alternating between the start and end of the new array, where the start index is incremented and the end index is decremented.